# Предотвратить пересоздание сервиса

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-service

Есть задача, чтобы `CountDownTimer` производил отсчет независимо от `Activity`. Для этого я вынес его в `Service`. Чтобы сервис работал в случае, когда ОС убьет активити, он запускается с помощью `startService`. Также, для надобностей управления таймером(приостановка отсчета, продолжение и т.д.), была использована привязка к сервису с помощью `bindService`. Но как показывают тесты, при смерти `Activity`, `Service` также убивается с последующим пересозданием (и выполнением методов `onStartCommand` и `onCreate`. Есть ли какой-то способ избежать такого поведения, кроме использования `setForeground`?

**UPD**
MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ServiceConnection serviceConnection;
    private String MAIN_ACTIVITY_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestService.class);
        startService(intent);
        serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                Log.d(MAIN_ACTIVITY_TAG,"Service connected");
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                Log.d(MAIN_ACTIVITY_TAG, "Service disconnected");
            }
        };
        bindService(new Intent(this, TestService.class), serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(MAIN_ACTIVITY_TAG, "MainActivity destroyed");
        unbindService(serviceConnection);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class TestService extends Service {

    private String SERVICE_TAG;
    private TestBinder binder = new TestBinder();

    public TestService() {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(SERVICE_TAG, "onStartCommand");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    public class TestBinder extends Binder {
        public TestService getService(){
            return TestService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SERVICE_TAG = TestService.class.getSimpleName();
        Log.d(SERVICE_TAG, "Service started");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(SERVICE_TAG, "Service stopped");
    }
}
```

Comment: у вас нигде не вызывается метод `unbindService()`?

Comment: Вызывается на `onDestroy` в `MainActivity`

Comment: Покажите код. Так будет легче определить проблему.

Comment: @MansurNashaev добавил код

Comment: `@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(MAIN_ACTIVITY_TAG, "MainActivity destroyed");
        unbindService(serviceConnection);
    }`

Здесь вы отсоединяетесь от сервиса, мне кажется проблема в этом. Проверьте что произойдет если это убрать

Comment: Тогда происходит утечка коннекшена `Activity com.testapp.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection`

Answer (score 1):

Перед запуском `Service`  проверяйте, запущен ли он на данный момент или нет:

```
 public static boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass, Context context) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Что мне это даст? Проблема в том, что `Service` перезапускается после закрытия `Activity`